# How to write a shell script counting all lines in all files in a given folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, word-count

I have a somewhat complicated task at hand, and - I have to admit to my shame - am not very skilled at all with shell scripting or the linux terminal in general, as I tend to just work in R.

So, what I want to do is to have write a shell script that does the following things, in chronological order:

1: ascertain today's date the following format `YYYY-MM-DD` and store it as a local variable or some equivalent. I tried the following:

```
todays-date=$(date '+%F')
```

2: move to the correct directory in which the data to be counted is located - this directory is the same as `todays-date`, and is all within the same parent directory structure. So, first of all, I do this:

```
cd /home/user/docs/parent/data
```

Then, I encounter my first issue when I try to access the directory with today's data:

```
cd echo $todays-date
```

This gives me an error, along the lines of 'no such file or directory'. So yeah, this is problem number 1.

3: Now I want the script to count all the lines in all the files located in this directory (let's assume I was able to access it). There should be 24 json files in this folder.

```
wc -l *
```

This works great. Now I'd like to save this information into a text file that is saved into my current working directory and named as follows: `'todays-date'_wordcount.txt`, so something like `2015-11-10_wordcount.txt`. I'm afraid I really don't know how to do this either.

The reason I want the date in there as a variable and not just written out is that I intend to run this shell script as a cron job once every day, as I have set up an automated data collection script and this shell script is there to count how many data were collected in the last iteration. It would be awesome if you guys could help me out! Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dash is not a valid character in variable name. Use underscore instead.

```
todays_date=$(date '+%F')
```

You can use the variable directly with `cd`, no `echo` needed:

```
cd "$todays_date"
```

To save the output of a command to a file, use redirection:

```
wc -l * > ~/"$todays_date"_wordcount.txt
```